# Filter list of lists in Scheme

Tags: list, calendar, scheme

I'm currently working on a scheme project and I've run in to some problems.
I'm trying to filter a list of lists, by searching for a specific element in the inner lists.

My inner lists and their combiner:

```
(define app1 (list "Doctor" 2015 10 31 09 00 2015 10 31 09 30))
(define app2 (list "Shop" 2015 11 04 16 45 2015 11 04 17 15))
(define app3 (list "Date" 2015 11 06 19 00 2015 11 07 00 00))
(define calendar1 (list app1 app2 app3))
```

I would like for the function to return the inner lists (in case of multiple) which matches the search result.

I currently have the follow code:

```
(define find-apps-by-title
  (lambda(calendar title)
    (filter (string=? (*) title) calendar)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to write on the star's (*) position. I've played around with (list-ref) but that requires me to input the inner lists, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
(define find-apps-by-title
  (lambda (calendar title)
    (filter (lambda (event) (string=? (car event) title))
            calendar)))
```

then

```
> (find-apps-by-title calendar1 "Shop")
'(("Shop" 2015 11 4 16 45 2015 11 4 17 15))
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot :) So basically, the (lambda(event) is every element the filter is going through?

Comment: The `(lambda (event) ...)` defines a function that `filter` applies to every element. If this function returns a non-false value, `filter` keeps the corresponding element.

Answer (score 3):

The question has been answered, but you could try an approach that is a little more declarative.

### Abstraction

Define functions for accessing parts of your data, because `car` exposes implementation details:

```
(define title-of
  (lambda (event)
    (car event)))
```

Define a function to filter a calendar by its title:

```
(define by-title
  (lambda (title)
    (lambda (event)
      (string=? (title-of event) title))))
```

Define what it means to find events.
The function below is a little trivial, but you could change it so that you can ask to find either *all* events or only the *first* one that matches your query, etc.

```
(define find-events
  (lambda (method calendar)
    (filter method calendar)))
```

Then, your define a calendar:

```
(define test-calendar
  '(("Doctor" 2015 10 31 09 00 2015 10 31 09 30)
    ("Shop" 2015 11 04 16 45 2015 11 04 17 15)
    ("Date" 2015 11 06 19 00 2015 11 07 00 00)))
```

And here is your query:

```
(find-events (by-title "Shop") test-calendar)
=> '(("Shop" 2015 11 04 16 45 2015 11 04 17 15))
```

### Structured format

Let's define another calendar, with more parenthesis:

```
(define other-calendar
  '(("Doctor" ((2015 10 31) (09 00)) ((2015 10 31) (09 30)))
    ("Shop"   ((2015 11 04) (16 45)) ((2015 11 04) (17 15)))
    ("Date"   ((2015 11 06) (19 00)) ((2015 11 07) (00 00)))))
```

Each event is structured as `(title begin end)`, where a date is `(date time)`, etc:

```
(define bdate (lambda (e) (second e)))
(define edate (lambda (e) (second e)))
(define date  (lambda (p) (first p)))
(define time  (lambda (p) (second p)))
(define year  (lambda (d) (first d)))
(define month (lambda (d) (second d)))
(define day   (lambda (d) (third d)))
(define hour    (lambda (x) (first x)))
(define minutes (lambda (x) (second x)))
```

Then, define other filters, like filter by date according to a time relation:

```
(define by-date 
  (lambda (relation)
    (lambda (event)
      (relation (bdate event)
                (edate event)))))
```

Tests whether a date is contained in the time interval of an event:

```
(define contains
  (lambda (yy mm dd)
    (lambda (beg end)
      (let ((bd (date b))
            (ed (date e)))
        (and (<= (year  bd) yy (day ed))
             (<= (month bd) mm (day ed))
             (<= (day   bd) dd (day ed)))))))
```

Combine multiple filters

```
(define join
  (lambda filters
    (lambda (event)
      (andmap (lambda (f) (f event)) filters))))
```

Finally:

```
(find-events (join (by-date (contains 2015 11 06))
                   (by-title "Date"))) 
   other-calendar)
=> '(("Date" ((2015 11 06) (19 00)) ((2015 11 07) (00 00))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the further support! I think I'll try restructuring my program  according to your answer.